# table clicked cell color scheme

Tags: javascript, css

I have menu in a table "mytable" like this:

```
<td id="1" align="center" onclick="clicked(1);"> one </td >
<td id="2" align="center" onclick="clicked(2);"> two </td >
<td id="3" align="center" onclick="clicked(3);"> three </td>
<td id="4" align="center" onclick="clicked(4);"> four </td> 
...
```

The css:

```
#mytable {
   background:#d0d0df;
   cursor:pointer;
}
#mytable td{
   background:#4092c4;
   color:#efefef;
}
#mytable td:hover{
   background:#e0e0e0;
   color:#FF004F;
}
```

The javascript:

```
function clicked(k){
   for (x=1; x<5; x++){ // reset all cells
      document.getElementById(x).style.background='#4092c4';
      document.getElementById(x).style.color='#efefef';
   }
   // set cell
   document.getElementById(k).style.background='#106284';
   document.getElementById(k).style.color='#FF004F';
}
```

How to highlight a single clicked cell and maintain the hover functionality? 
The above code works, but after calling clicked() the hovering functionality is lost.
I rather not use jquery.

Comment: can you make a JSFiddle ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/photobank/9zFKu/

Comment: On a side note I strongly suggest you reconsider using a `table` for a simple menu. A well styled list (`ul`) will serve you better in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

Syntax issue, ids that are just numbers are not valid HTML.

The problem you are having is that when the javascript runs, it appends the styles inline on the elements, and the CSS styles cannot override inline (not without adding things like `!important`, and that just gets ugly).

I would steer away from writing styling in the JS, just use it to change classes. So make a new class, lets call it `.active`, and when you click a tablecell just add the class, and remove the class from all the others.

Something like (this is example only, some tweaking may be required)

```
function clicked(k){
    var otherCell, thisCell;
    for (x=1; x<5; x++){ // reset all cells
        otherCell = document.getElementById(x);
        otherCell.className = otherCell.className.replace('active','');

    }
    // set cell as active
    thisCell = document.getElementById(k);
    thisCell.className += thisCell.className + ' active';
}
```

and then set the styles only in css, something like

```
#mytable {
    background:#d0d0df;
    cursor:pointer;
}
#mytable td{
    background:#4092c4;
    color:#efefef;
}

#mytable td.active{
    background:#106284;
    color:#efefef;
}

#mytable td:hover{
    background:#e0e0e0;
    color:#FF004F;
}
```

This way you have more control over the 'cascading' of the style rules, being more specific or  changing the order of the rules will give you possible different outcomes.

As per fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4W295/1/)

Comment: thank you - it works fine as a bonus I have learned a bit of jsfiddle too!

Answer (score 1):

This is probably overkill, but the [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) javascript library makes this trivial.

I've channged the HTML too becuase using `table` for non-tabula data should be avoided.

**New HTML:**

```
<ul id="mytable">
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>three</li>
    <li>four</li>
</ul>
```

Also note, no ID's on the items and no in-line javascript, nice and clean.

**New CSS:**

```
#mytable {
    background:#d0d0df;
    cursor:pointer;
    list-style:none;
    padding-left:0;
}
#mytable li {
    background:#4092c4;
    color:#efefef;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:2px -2px 2px 2px;
    padding:3px;
}
#mytable li:hover {
    background:#e0e0e0;
    color:#FF004F;
}
#mytable li.active {
    background:#106284;
    color:#efefef;
}
```

Note: I've used `inline-block` for the list items to orientate the horizontaly, you could also use `float` or `table-cell`. This is a good article on [floats vs inline-blocl](http://robertnyman.com/2010/02/24/css-display-inline-block-why-it-rocks-and-why-it-sucks/). Also note the new `active` class.

Now for the super-simple jquery (make sure to include the jquery library!)

```
$(document).ready(function(){ //Performs the following code when the document is fully loaded
   //Assigns a click event handler to list items in an element with ID "myTable"
   $("#mytable li").click(function () {
       //Remove the active class from list items in #mytable that were not clicked
       $("#mytable li").not($(this)).removeClass("active");
       //Add the active class to the clicked element.
       $(this).addClass("active");
   });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9zFKu/1/)

Just make sure to [include the jquery library](http://encosia.com/3-reasons-why-you-should-let-google-host-jquery-for-you/) and to use `$(document).ready();`

**Handy jQuery Links**

- [Document Ready](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)
- [Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)
- [Click](http://api.jquery.com/click/)
- [Not](http://api.jquery.com/%3anot/)
- [Add Class](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/)
- [Remove Class](http://api.jquery.com/removeclass/)